# diskpart select by disk label

Tags: batch-file, disk-partitioning, winpe

I need to select a disk in WinPE using DISKPART by label. I found this but I think it's outdated:

```
@Echo %dbg%Off
::
:: Find External drive and set it active
:: Lists Disk Information using Diskpart
::
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
:: Type the frst 11 characters of the label of the drive here. 
Set _FindLabel=Recovery
Call :_InitVars "%_FindLabel%"
"%SystemRoot%\system32\FSUTIL.exe">Nul 2>&1||Goto _NotAdmin
Echo.
Echo.Please wait, gathering info on the installed drives
Echo.
>"%_Dscr1%" Echo.List disk
For /F "Tokens=2" %%I In ('Diskpart /S "%_Dscr1%"^|Findstr /I /R /C:"Disk [0-9]"') Do (
(Echo.Select Disk %%I
Echo.Detail Disk)>>"%_OFile1%"
)
For /F "Tokens=1,2,3*" %%I In ('Diskpart /S "%_OFile1%"^|Findstr /I /R /C:"Disk             [0-9]" /C:"Volume [0-9]"') Do (
  If /I %%I==Disk (
Set _Tmp=%%J:
) Else (
Set _Label=%%L
Set _Label=!_Label:~,11!
>>"%_OFile2%" Echo.!_Tmp!%%J:!_Label!
))
If Exist "%_OFile1%" Del "%_OFile1%"
For /F "Usebackq Tokens=1-3 Delims=:" %%I In ("%_OFile2%") Do (
Set _Label=%%K
Set _Label=!_Label:~,11!
If "!_Label!"=="%_FindLabel%" (Set _Disk=%%I) & (Set _Label=%%K) & Goto _FDisk
>>"%_OFile1%" Echo.Volume %%J on Disk %%I has the Label %%K
)
Echo.
Echo.There is no drive connected that has the label of "%_FindLabel%"
Echo.These are the currently connected volumes:
Type "%_OFile1%"
:_Exit
Echo.
Pause
Goto _Cleanup
:_FDisk
(Echo.Select disk %_Disk%
Echo.Select Partition 1
Echo.Active)>"%_Dscr1%"
Diskpart /S "%_Dscr1%"
:_Cleanup
For %%I In ("%_Dscr1%" "%_OFile1%" "%_OFile2%") Do Del %%I>Nul 2>&1
Goto :EOF
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::           Subroutines
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:_NotAdmin
Ver|Findstr /I /C:"Version 5">Nul
If %Errorlevel%==0 (Set _Tmp1=5) & (Set _Tmp=a Computer Administrator account)
Ver|Findstr /I /C:"Version 6">Nul
If %Errorlevel%==0 (Set _Tmp1=6) & (Set _Tmp=an Elevated Command Prompt)
Echo.
Echo.This program must be run from %_Tmp%.
If %_Tmp1%==6 Echo.Please Right click the file, then click Run as Administrator
Echo.Exiting program
Goto _Exit
:_InitVars
For /F "Tokens=1 Delims==" %%I In ('Set _ 2^>Nul') Do Set %%I=
Set _Dscr1=%temp%\dpscr1.txt
Set _OFile1=%temp%\_OFile1.txt
Set _OFile2=%temp%\_OFile2.txt
Set _FindLabel=%~1
Set _FindLabel=%_FindLabel:~,20%
Call :_Cleanup
```

When I run it, it returns:

```
Please wait, gathering info on the installed drives

There is no drive connected that has the label of "Recovery"
These are the currently connected volumes:
Volume 1 on Disk 0 has the Label NTFS   Part
Volume 2 on Disk 0 has the Label NTFS   Part
Volume 3 on Disk 1 has the Label WINPE
```

It's showing the Fs (filesystem), not the label.

Diskpart output (list volume)

```
Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
Volume 0     D   USBBOOT      UDF    DVD-ROM      329 MB  Healthy
Volume 1         Windows      NTFS   Partition     40 GB  Healthy
Volume 2         Recovery     NTFS   Partition     19 GB  Healthy
Volume 3     Z   WINPE        FAT32  Removable   7632 MB  Healthy
```

Not sure how to modify this to get it to select the Label column.

Answer (score 2):

As there is missing valid drive letter in some lines of the Diskpart output (`list volume`, column `ltr`), then tokens in line #19

```
For /F "Tokens=1,2,3*" %%I In ('Diskpart /S "%_OFile1%"^|Findstr /I /R /C:"Disk [0-9]" /C:"Volume [0-9]"') Do (
```

display as follows (and we have our culprit now):

```
%%I    %%J  %%K      %%L
Volume 0    D        USBBOOT      UDF    DVD-ROM      329 MB ...
Volume 1    Windows  NTFS   Partition     40 GB  Healthy
Volume 2    Recovery NTFS   Partition     19 GB  Healthy
Volume 3    Z        WINPE        FAT32  Removable   7632 MB ...
```

Therefore you could use next snippet code (instead of lines 19..26) in your script:

```
For /F "Tokens=1*" %%I In ('Diskpart /S "%_OFile1%"^|Findstr /I /R /C:"Disk [0-9]" /C:"Volume [0-9]"') Do (
  If /I %%I==Disk (
    Set _Tmp=%%J:
) Else (
    Set _Label=%%J
    Set _Label=!_Label:~10,11!
>>"%_OFile2%" Echo.!_Tmp!%%J:!_Label!
))
```

Care this change interferes `_Tmp` variable!